# Why the line in the shapefile does not align with the base map reference Runway?

Tags: coordinate-system, shapefile, alignment

I created a shapefile and set the coordinate system to **WGS 1984 UTM zone 45N**, and I added the base map Imagery with Labels.

I created a line feature with Coordinates of two ends of the runway

- (27°41'1.694"N  85°21'12.202"E)
- and (27°42’30.058’’ N  085°21’52.283’’ E)

The line correctly aligns the runway center line, but the direction of the line does not match with the actual direction of the runway .

**Example:** When I draw a line with the runway length **1339.5m** and **heading 22°**  from  **point(27°41'1.694"N  85°21'12.202"E)**, the line does not aligns with the runway centerline.

the direction of the runway is 22° from the (27°41'1.694"N  85°21'12.202"E)

Comment: Screenshots of the runway and line would probably help, as well as the name of the GIS software you're using. Edit your question to add those things if you have them.

Answer (score 1):

The heading of 22 degree is probably for the geographic coordinates, not projected coordinates in the UTM zone 45N. The heading varies with every point in a projected system.

You can quickly see the difference in QGIS. First draw a line straight north in the UTM 45N projection. Then draw a line straight north in EPSG4326. The screenshot show the difference.

[image]

Comment: Additionally, it's not clear where the heading is coming from. But typically the runway names/headings/numbers are also referenced to local magnetic North, not geographic north.

Comment: @PhilippNagel  Thank you for reminding me about the heading reference, i was taking the geographic heading as the runway direction, but actually runway direction is in Magnetic Heading

Comment: @Dennis Bauszus ,  I redraw with the projected coordinates considering the magnetic declination , i got the correct heading , anyway thank you very much